# Solana Package Breaking React App UX

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, react

I am adding quite a few solana related packages to an existing React-App I've been building and it seems one of the packages has a dependency that's breaking my UX.

[image: error message]

Anyone seen this error? It seems to have something to do with this dependency not being compatible with Webpack 5. I'm not even sure which of my packages has this dependency in the first place. These are all of the solana packages I'm adding:

```
"@babel/runtime": "^7.15.5",
"@civic/solana-gateway-react": "^0.7.0",
"@identity.com/solana-gateway-ts": "^0.8.1",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
"@project-serum/anchor": "^0.17.0",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.7.0",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui": "^0.13.1",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.13.1",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.6.1",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.11.3",
"@solana/web3.js": "^1.33.0",
```

Comment: please replace the screenshot with a code block of the text.  it will improve seo for the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use @solana/wallet-adapter-.. with react JS?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/can-i-use-solana-wallet-adapter-with-react-js)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a missing transient dependency.

Consider installing it manually:

with npm:

```
npm i @ledgerhq/devices
```

with yarn:

```
yarn add @ledgerhq/devices
```

---

If this is a new react app, will advice you using one of these starters instead:

https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-dapp-next

https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter

Comment: Does this worked ?