# Solana-wallet-adapter is not working properly in react app

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, web3.js, walletadapter

```
"@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.5",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "0.15.9",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "0.9.12",
"@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "0.17.2",
```

These are the dependencies installed in my dapp but this error occurs : 'WalletProvider as an ancestor of the component that uses WalletContext'

[image: Error screen short]

Comment: What version of React are you using? Did you start with a known working example?

Comment: I am using react 17.0.2 . This error occurred while I was switching the old one  to the latest. In the old one there was this issue : https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/solana-package-breaking-react-app-ux

Comment: Use the starter example in that post and react 18. Get the example working and add on from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topmost error ‘You have tried to read `wallets` on a `WalletContext` without providing one’ is the error to heed.

Make sure to include a `<WalletProvider>` at least one component above the one in which you try to read from it.

See [setup](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter#setup) for an example.