# Can I use @solana/wallet-adapter with react JS?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, react

I create a new React JS (`npx create-react-app`) I install the dependencies to connect a Wallet to my application:

```
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.17.0",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.7.0",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui": "^0.13.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.13.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.6.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.11.3",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.33.0",
```

But I get errors when I import:

```
import {
  getPhantomWallet,
  getSlopeWallet,
  getSolflareWallet,
  getSolletExtensionWallet,
  getSolletWallet,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets";
```

Error:

```
./node_modules/@ledgerhq/hw-transport-webhid/lib-es/TransportWebHID.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@ledgerhq/devices/hid-framing' in 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\saude-vapor-2-0\saudevapor\node_modules\@ledgerhq\hw-transport- webhid\lib-es'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to use "@solana/wallet-adapter-..." in ReactJS applications?

I use this doc: https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/candy-machine-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a webpack issue. You are using the old versions of the packages which aren't compatible with Ledger. Use this directory as a starter for your React app: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter/create-react-app-starter

Comment: One thing, do you know if exists this starter in pure js? Im still learning typescript, and all my aplication is in js already.

Comment: You can easily convert the starter to JS in three four steps. Do the following:
1. rename index.tsx and App.tsx to index.js and App.js
2. remove reportWebVitals import statement and declaration from index.js
3. change the Components style from TS to JS:
  (i) `const App: FC = () => { ` becomes `function App() {`
  (ii) `const Context: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {` becomes `function Context() {`
  (iii) `const Content: FC = () => {` becomes `function Content() {`

This should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this simple & easy-to-follow guide to follow the latest steps for integrating the wallet adapter in your dapp.

https://www.solanawalletadapter.xyz/

Hope it helps.